# how can i change selected value of drop list dynamically

Tags: javascript, asp.net

i want to pick the value from text box and then change the value of dropdown list according to that value

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            function change()
            {
                var value = document.getElementById('text').value;
                document.getElementById("Model").selectedvalue = value
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="Model" AutoPostBack="false" runat="server" CssClass="styled">
            <asp:ListItem Value="None">None</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="Enum">Enum</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="Sum">Sum</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="Multi">Multi</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="Xaxis">Xaxis</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>
        <input id="text" type="text"/>
        <input type="button" onclick="change();"/>
    </body>
<html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change `document.getElementById("Model").selectedvalue=valye` to `document.getElementById("<% = Model.ClientID %>").options.value=valye`

Comment: What is the deference between that two ? :?

Comment: Model is asp control and its id is not going to be static but will be generated based on page control hierarchy. Model.ClientID will give actual id of drop down. Please give reason when you down vote

Answer (score 0):

This may can help you http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaScript/Form-Control/SelectinganOptionUsingJavaScript.htm

Answer (score 0):

You can do this easily with jquery using following code

```
 function change()
    {
      $("#Model option[value='"+ $('#text').val()+"']").attr('selected', 'selected');    
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

your code will never find the Model, if you are using .NET 4 you can add

```
CLientIdMode="Static"
```

to your drop down list

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="Model" AutoPostBack="false" runat="server" ClientIdMode="Static" CssClass="styled">
        <asp:ListItem Value="None">None</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="Enum">Enum</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="Sum">Sum</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="Multi">Multi</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="Xaxis">Xaxis</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>
```

Which means your

```
document.getElementById("Model").selectedvalue = value
```

will now find the control

Answer (score 0):

you must write this :

```
document.getElementById("Model").value = value;
```

instead of your line :

```
document.getElementById("Model").selectedvalue = value;
```

More over if you are using master page @hungryMind answer is also correct, 
because in javascript there is **.value** not .selectedvalue.